# Django when clicked show another model attribute

Tags: python, html, django

I'm trying to make window where some text will be shown in one language, when clicked second language will appear. I've created one model which consists every information about post.

**model.py**

```
from django.db import models
from datetime import datetime   
from django.contrib.auth.models import User

def get_default_user():
    return User.objects.get(id=1)

class EveryPost(models.Model):
    title_pl = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    title_ru = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True)
    text_pl = models.TextField(blank=True)
    text_ru = models.TextField(blank=True)
    date = models.DateTimeField(default=datetime.now, blank=True)
    User = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE, default=get_default_user)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.title_pl
```

**html**

```
    {% for obj in EveryPost %}
        <div class="card text-center">
            <div class="card-header">
                <ul class="nav nav-tabs card-header-tabs">
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-main" href="{% url 'rupl' obj.pk %}">PL</a>
                </li>
                <li class="nav-item">
                    <a class="nav-link nav-main" href="{% url 'plru' obj.pk %}">RU</a>
                </li>
                </ul>
            </div>
            <div class="card-body">
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'detailpost' obj.pk %}">{{ obj.title_pl }}</a></h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ obj.text_pl|truncatechars:350 }}</p>
                <a href="{% url 'detailpost' obj.pk %}" class="btn btn-dark float-right">Zobacz </a>
            </div>
            <div class="card-footer text-muted">
                <span class="float-left">{{ obj.date|date:"d M y" }}</span>
                <span class="float-right">Przesłane przez: {{ obj.User }}</span>
            </div>
        </div>
    {% endfor %}
```

I've tried to make switch between text_pl and text_ru but it wasn't a good idea(lost data)

**views.py**

```
def plru(request, pk):
    post = EveryPost.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.text_pl = post.text_ru
    post.title_pl = post.title_ru
    post.save()
    return redirect('index')

def rupl(request, pk):
    post = EveryPost.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.text_ru = post.text_pl
    post.title_ru = post.title_pl
    post.save()
    return redirect('index')
```

[Image explaining what i want to achieve](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5AgHW.jpg)

Comment: Maybe you'd better consider using [i18n](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.0/topics/i18n/) localization feature "out of the box"?

Comment: I think its better to use tab pages to achieve this: https://www.w3schools.com/howto/howto_js_tabs.asp

Comment: @ruddra one more thing, when i open web i see both post (in both languages) but when i click i see proper only one language. Did you have similiar problem?

Comment: nope. probably you need to put a default active tab

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it, perhaps it's not most efficient way, but works though :)

I add one extra element in **model**:
`version_pl = models.BooleanField(default=True)`

So in **HTML** it check whether is True or False:

```
            <div class="card-body">
            {% if obj.version_pl == False %}
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'detailpost' obj.pk %}">{{ obj.title_ru }}</a></h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ obj.text_ru|truncatechars:350 }}</p>
            {% else %}
                <h5 class="card-title"><a href="{% url 'detailpost' obj.pk %}">{{ obj.title_pl }}</a></h5>
                <p class="card-text">{{ obj.text_pl|truncatechars:350 }}</p>
            {% endif %}
                <a href="{% url 'detailpost' obj.pk %}" class="btn btn-dark float-right">Zobacz całość</a>
            </div>
```

and **views.py**

```
def rupl(request, pk):
    post = EveryPost.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.version_pl = True
    post.save()
    return redirect('index')

def plru(request, pk):
    post = EveryPost.objects.get(pk=pk)
    post.version_pl = False
    post.save()
    return redirect('index')
```

Thanks for replies

Answer (score 0):

there's no need for lot's of functions and urls,
simple is better:
in views.py:

```
def post_detail(request, post_id):
     post = get_or_404(Post, id= post_id)
     return render(request, 'post_details.html")
```

in post_details.html:

```
<div id="post_in_1st_lng" style="visibility: visible;">
    {{ post.title_pl }}
</div>
<div id="post_in_2nd_lng" style="visibility: hidden;">
    {{ post.title_ru }}
</div>
<button id="lan_change">Change Language </button>

<script>
     $("#lan_change").on('click', function (){
          first_vis = $("#post_in_1st_lng").css('visibility') == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
          sec_vis = $("#post_in_2nd_lng").css('visibility') == "visible" ? "hidden" : "visible";
          $("#post_in_2nd_lng").css('visibility', sec_vis);
          $("#post_in_1st_lng").css('visibility', first_vis);
     });
</script>
```

this is a simple jQuery solution.
another way is using ajax, but since the post object is the same one, so text in both languages are already loaded, so no need for time wasting server call.